# Are humans still bipedal if a child is born without legs?

Tags: philosophy-of-biology, human-rights, counterfactuals

I am aware of a type philosophical argument that relies on a single counterexample to falsify an absolute statement:

- All swans are white.
- But here is a black swan. Your claim is false.

But I have encountered what I believe to be an invalid application of this logic:

- Humans are bipedal.
- But this person was born without legs (for [developmental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congenital_amputation) or [genetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phocomelia) reasons). Your claim is false.

This takes place in a wider discussion of access and disability where both parties want to motivate for better access, but disagree how to frame the discussion. My intuition is that the following is reasonable logic:

- Humans are bipedal. (In fact I think this statement is irrelevant, but I include it for completeness.)
- A publicly funded building should accommodate everyone, including those born without legs.
- The building should include wheelchair ramps.

And in my opinion the following is invalid. This doesn't matter too much, but in my opinion poor arguments undermine trust:

- A publicly funded building should accommodate everyone.
- Humans are not bipedal. (Some are born without legs.)
- The building should include wheelchair ramps.

Two people are arriving at the same conclusion in very different ways. Without getting sidetracked by a discussion of disabilities, can someone articulate the differing philosophies (and/or errors) being expressed here?

Comment: Humans are defined by their genes not by external facts.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, that doesn't really answer the question.  You could generalize the question to meet the challenge to say "well, what if someone had a genetic anomaly which prevented the development of legs?" You'd struggle, I think, to say that they were not human.

Comment: I've added an example of a genetic cause, and updated the tags (hopefully correct)

Comment: @PaulRoss I sometimes find I want to "generalize the question to meet the challenge" because someone has missed the point (or my question was poorly thought out) -- is there a name for that? happy to post another question :)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA by the way I want to be clear I appreciate your feedback, it makes the question better! this is just a great example of something I have encountered

Comment: If somebody makes a legless argument, does philosophy still confuse undergrads?

Comment: This one is easy: the definition of bipedal just needs to be amended to say that in 99.9999% of cases humans are born with 2 legs.

Comment: They are not arriving at the conclusion in different ways. Both arguments are, essentially, identical, because the (non) bipedality premises are irrelevant in *both* cases. In fact, "bipedal" is ambiguous, so, depending on the sense used, one can justifiably assert or deny it for humans. The arguments are valid but unsound. "A publicly funded building should accommodate everyone" premise is false, it is simply unfeasible for all public buildings to "accommodate everyone". Both sides need a better reason as to why *this* particular building should accommodate people without legs in particular.

Comment: These exceptional cases violating the monotonicity property of logic are usually dealt with in semantic networks and description logic in the field of ontology engineering and knowledge representation via default reasoning and exceptional value overriding using the inheritance or other procedural mechanism, without any worry about the default bipedal attribute of the human category...

Comment: Your example is a "bad copy" of Aristotle approach... Aristotle's definition of "human" was NOT that humans are "featherless bipeds". The definition (according to A) must be [based on *essence*](https://reasonandmeaning.com/2014/10/17/theories-of-human-nature-chapter-9-aristotle-part-1/) and the essence stay unchanged also when the "particular" is subject to accidental changes: a legs has been cutted-off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the arguments, or differences in opinion, which can be encountered in philosophy are arguments at cross-purpose, where people are using the same words but attributing different meanings to them. When someone says 'swans can fly', what they mean is shorthand for the fact that it is in the nature of swans generally that they are able to fly. You can find exceptions- such as swans with damaged wings- but that does not invalidate the statement 'swans can fly'. Likewise when someone says humans are bipedal they mean that humans are usually born with two legs- they don't mean that every human has two legs.

You are right in thinking that that the statement 'humans are bipedal' is irrelevant to the argument about the need for wheelchairs. Even someone with two legs might still need a wheelchair, if their legs were paralysed for example. And if humans were quadrupeds, some of them might still need a wheelchair.

Comment: Perhaps "the human species is bipedal" does not imply "all humans are born with two legs"

Answer (score 3):

Humans are not defined by "bipedal". Its like you are not defined by "member of philosophy.stackexchange.com". You were still you when you were not member of this site.

If you think you are not same you then by what right you got all possessions, job and wife/husband of the previous you? You have to agree that its same you or you have to let go of those things, or go to jail.

As per law of land where you live only someone who has same identity as you can have those things.

Ofcourse some changed happened in you when you became member here but it dont change your identity. You will be considered the same you by everybody who is not pedantic. Going on the other path is too cumbersome to ever be followed. You have to, if you try to follow it, continuously redefine things around you because everything around you is changing continuously. The furniture, the air, the ground, everyhing.

Cut off some human's legs, is he still a human? Yes, ofcourse. The identity is not changed. Cut all parts, take them away, is it a human in front of you? No, there is nothing in front of you, so no human. At some point whats left ceased to be human.

Cut only head of a human, take the head away. Is the remaining a human? No, its a corpse.

Cut heart away. No human left.

Cut stomach away. Whats left is still a human.

Cut entirety of intestines away. Whats left is a corpse.

As long as what you cut away or is cut away naturally or never formed dont prevent the body to ever be alive and dont kill, you have a human.

Answer (score -1):

The nature of a word like "humans" is that it is a fuzzy, "I know it when I see it" type of concept. There is no exhaustive definition of what is a human and what is not that works in every conceivable circumstance.

To see this, consider: Who was the first human? Or, equivalently, when exactly did the species 'homo sapiens' emerge? We cannot pin this down to a single individual or generation, even in principle. Evolution works gradually, by degrees. There wasn't a single generation where your ancestors were suddenly "homo sapiens" when they were definitely something else in the generation before. They instead became gradually more human-like - more upright, larger brains, more human-like body and skull shape - over many generations. There's no single point where we can draw the line.

We can say that the distinction in your ancestors between "human" and "non-human" is fuzzy, in the sense of [fuzzy logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic). The truth value of "X is a human" need not be only 0% or 100%; it can smoothly take on values in between, such as 91% or 99%.

This is an example of the [Sorites paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox). The Sorites paradox applies to virtually every natural-language category of things in the real world.

We define the category of humans by fuzzy analogy. A human without legs is still "enough of a human" - similar enough to more "standard" examples of humans - that we would call them a human. A human without arms, is still similar enough. How about a human mutant born with gills? Still, probably, we'd call them a human. But if they have *enough* traits dissimilar to the "standard" example of a human - perhaps they have gills, fins, a fish tail - at some point some (not all) people would start to say, "okay, maybe we need another word for this person."

Visually, we don't have a crisp category of "humans" like this:

[image: crisp humans]

The category is instead fuzzy at the edges, like this:

[image: fuzzy humans]

Comment: This is helpful in that I don't believe the statement "humans are bipedal" is fuzzy, and I think this was part of the disagreement, so your pointer to the Sorites paradox is very helpful. I will investigate it and probably post more specific questions about the philosophy of science and Sorites :)

Comment: @LeeMcGee "Humans are bipedal" is indeed fuzzy. It doesn't mean "literally all humans have two legs." Rather it means that humans *almost* always have two legs, like 99.9% of the time. If the proportion of humans with a number of legs other than two were to increase to as large as 50%, then "humans are bipedal" would not be regarded as accurate. But the exact percentage where it is no longer regarded as accurate depends on the proportion in a fuzzy way.